# Excel vba running differently on two computers

Tags: vba, excel

I am pulling my hair out over this as I cannot see why this isn't working. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have inherited a macro in Excel which runs differently depending on which PC we run it on. Essentially, the macro inserts blank rows into a table of data (which should also have conditional formatting to make it blue to break up the table and make it easier to read). On my PC instead of a blank row being entered, it is a row of #ref errors and loses the formatting.

We have a different macro assigned to a button which runs three macros one after another. The one I have the issue with is the third of these three. When I run the macros as three separate events it works, but together it has the #ref errors.

[image: It should look like this]

[image: But actually looks like this]

Sorry for the small snippet of the file, but it is sensitive information.

I have tried adding a pause in between the second and third, but this doesn't help.

Are there some security settings which I should check?

The macro looks at a formula in column A and looks for the number 5 and inserts a row after this line. The code is as follows:-

```
Sub Main()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While Range("A" & i).Value <> ""

If Left(Range("a" & i), 2) = "5" Then
    i = i + 1
    Rows(i).Insert
    Range("A" & i).Value = Range("a" & i - 1).Value

End If

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

What I am struggling to get my head around is that it works in isolation, but not when run with other macros. For completeness the macro which runs the three has the following code:-

```
Sub runall_CVR()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call hiderows_CVR
Call Delete0s_cvr
Call Main

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Many thanks

James

Comment: Out of curiosity: why `Left(Range("a" & i), 2) = "5"`? The 2 tells to look for the 2 leftmost characters, while compared to "5" which has a length of 1. (something like `CStr` would do the same)

Comment: Have you tried to set cut/copy to `False`? I don't know what the other macros are doing, but still having something in copy may lead to that problem.. Also you should include the full reference which includes the sheet you are working with...

Comment: To be honest, as I inherited the spreadsheet, I don't fully understand it. I will try amending the 2 to 1 and see if that makes a difference. Or maybe removing entirely. The formula produces results which aren't all numeric, but I can easily change it so that it is.

Comment: You should not change the 2 to a 1 as "52" also would evaluate to true that way...

Comment: The other macros do use copy and paste so what you're saying could make sense. If I set cut/copy to false, do I need to turn it back in afterwards? Thank you so much for your comments, I will definitely try these out when I am back in the office.

Comment: The results only ever go up to 5, so 52 wouldn't ever happen. The results are only in the range 0 to 5.

Comment: You do not "re-set" it back in any way. Just `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is all you need to do. If you need to paste it later on again, you just need to "copy" it again... that is all. :)

Comment: Can you add the formula that's giving the #REF! error to your question?

Comment: Dirk, the cutcopymode worked! Thank you so much for helping. It makes sense as recently excel has started holding copied data in the clipboard and holding longer than it used to. The insert command was inserting the copied cells, not just inserting a blank row. Thanks again.